# CSS styling overridden by another component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

I have a React project and a page that has the following components:

```
return (
   <div>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
   </div>
);
```

Both `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` have integrated with the same component, let's call it `CommonComponent`. It looks like this (simplified):

```
const CommonComponent = (props) => {
  return <span className={`commonComponentStyling, ${props.providedStyling}`}>
            {props.text}
         </span>
}
```

CSS of `CommonComponent`:

```
.commonComponentStyling {
   color: red;
}
```

The integration with `CommonComponent` looks like this:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
   return (
      <CommonComponent providedStyling={'stylingComponentA'} text="Foo" />
   )
}
```

with CSS:

```
.stylingComponentA {
    color: blue;
}
```

---

```
const ComponentB = () => {
   return (
      <CommonComponent providedStyling={'stylingComponentB'} text="Bar" />
   )
}
```

with CSS:

```
.stylingComponentB {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

**Problem:** I am experiencing a problem where if I were to only render `ComponentA` on my page, the text `Foo` will be correctly rendered in blue color. However, if I were to also render `ComponentB` on the same page, the text `Foo` will now be rendered in red colour (it switches back to the default styling of `CommonComponent`).

While `Foo` will not have a bold font, it's not longer in the correct colour, even though I am using CSS modules.

Can someone help explain what's happening here, why and how?

Comment: Is it a typo that your classes inside `className` start with `.`?

Comment: @Konrad Apologies, yes. Let me fix that.

Comment: I have other issues, but they are getting fixed by removing the `,` from the `className` string https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mendeleev-tkw5nn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is it possible that the classes are interpreted into different order than in `className` ? Might be helpful to check which class is taking the priority.